# FF issue with textboxes in HTML5 Sortable

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using this sortable plugin: [HTML5 Sortable](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/)

It works great, unless I'm in FF, then because I have textboxes in the list items, i can sort, but I cannot select the text or click anywhere except position 0 and thus my users would have to rely on the keyboard which is ridiculous.

To see what I'm saying, download it [here](https://github.com/farhadi/html5sortable), and add this html above the Sortable List:

```
   <section>
     <h2>Sortable Inputs</h2>
        <ul class="sortable inputs">
          <li><input type="text" id="item1" name="item1" value="Item 1" /></li>
          <li><input type="text" id="item2" name="item2" value="Item 2" /></li>
          <li><input type="text" id="item3" name="item3" value="Item 3" /></li>
          <li><input type="text" id="item4" name="item4" value="Item 4" /></li>
          <li><input type="text" id="item5" name="item5" value="Item 5" /></li>
          <li><input type="text" id="item6" name="item6" value="Item 6" /></li>
        </ul>
   </section>
```

I've searched all over the internet for a solution without success!  Please help!